# SQL for search query with multiple table join

Tags: php, sql, join

I have following tables

> **document**
>
> - docid (PK)
> - url
>
> **wdata**
>
> - wordid (PK)
> - word
>
> **wtitle**
>
> - wordid
> - docid
>
> (wordid & docid combined unique)
>
> **wurl**
>
> - wordid
> - docid
>
> (wordid & docid combined unique)

For searching any phrase I break it into words and get its `wordid`.  Tables `wtitle`,`wurl` are to be used in scoring of rows for ranking. I intend to add more tables for scoring like inlink , inh1 tag etc. However I am having problem framing my sql query for search words.

My SQL query is like

```
SELECT d.docid,furl,IF(t.wordid IS NULL,0,1) AS intitle,IF(u.wordid IS NULL,0,1) AS inurl FROM document d
LEFT JOIN wtitle t ON t.docid=d.docid
LEFT JOIN wdata w ON w.wordid=t.wordid
LEFT JOIN wurl u ON u.wordid=w.wordid AND u.docid=d.docid
WHERE w.wordid IN (wordid1,wordid2,wordid3)
```

I have following doubts

1. How to check each table `wtitle` and `wurl` both or even more as presently it is searching 1st in wtitle because of LEFT JOIN and other joins are ignored ?
2. How to properly frame this SQL Query ?

   SQL FIddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ab0052/4/0

Wordid 3 is in URL but not in title of Docid 2

Wordid 3 is not in URL but in title of Docid 3

I want to return both doc 2 and 3 however because it joins by wtitle first it is ignoring (using 1st query data) other joins

Comment: What could help you is to create some brief test data and just verify it for yourself.  See if you can get the values to match up.

Comment: Note that `LEFT JOIN w ... WHERE w = ...` is the same as `INNER JOIN w...`

Comment: For futher help, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I already tried it , when I deleted rows for a particular `docid` in `wtitle` but kept it in `wurl` for same `wordid` that `docid` stopped showing in result

Comment: Have added the fiidle, can somebody help now !

Comment: You are looking for documents containing certain words in either the title or the url. So when looking for two words, do you want to see only documents containing *both* words or are you fine with documents containing only one of the words, too?

Comment: Preferably both words , If I can solve for many words then I can query separately for single words too... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know whether, say, two word you are looking for occur *both* in a document, you must look at title and url combined. (Otherwise if you knew that one of the words existed in title and one word existed in url, you wouldn't know if it's the same word or both words.) So combine both tables with `UNION ALL` first, but remember which record belongs to which table. Then we can count combined and per place (title or url).

Here is a query that looks for word IDs 3 and 4. It lists the entries matching both words first followed by documents with only one of the words matching:

```
SELECT 
  d.docid, 
  d.furl, 
  w.cnt_combined,
  w.cnt_in_title,
  w.cnt_in_url
FROM document d
JOIN
(
  select
    docid,
    count(distinct wordid) cnt_combined,
    sum(place = 'TITLE') cnt_in_title,
    sum(place = 'URL') cnt_in_url
  from
  (
    select 'TITLE' as place, docid, wordid from wtitle where wordid in (3,4)
    union all
    select 'URL' as place, docid, wordid from wurl where wordid in (3,4)
  ) both_tables
  group by docid
) w ON w.docid = d.docid
order by w.cnt_combined desc;
```

You can look for words instead of word IDs by replacing

```
where wordid in (3,4)
```

by

```
where wordid in (select wordid from wdata where word in ('vaccination', 'the'))
```

Rextester link: http://rextester.com/KPVX67861 (SQL fiddle doesn't work for me most of the time.)

I suggest these covering indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_wtitle ON wtitle(wordid, docid);
CREATE INDEX idx_wurl ON wurl(wordid, docid);
```

With `wordid` first the DBMS can find the entries easily, and as `docid` is already in the indexes, the DBMS doesn't have to access the table. It gets all data from the indexes. (This is why they are called covering indexes; they cover all columns the query wants.)

Comment: Wow thanks a lot, I really liked this idea of alias for `place` and adding the sum, it certainly gave me some idea, however your SQL query does not use index properly and for me with 10 million data in `wdata` table and large `wdoc` table it is taking minutes to execute this search query. 

Since you are using `UNION` I shifted WHERE condition inside for better performance ! Something closer to what I wanted ! Perhaps I can do UNION ALL with many point tables and sum up to get score or count  ! Thank you for help !

Comment: Yes moving the WHERE clause inside and apply it to the tables directly is a good idea. (I am used to Oracle where its great optimizer does just that internally, so I don't have to write the same condition twice. Seems I'm a bit spoiled ;-) I recommend to have the following two indexes to have this run as fast as possible: `wtitle(wordid, docid)` and `wurl(wordid, docid)`. It's important to have `wordid` first in these indexes, so they can be found quickly. The DBMS doesn't even have to read the tables anymore, because it gets the `docid` straight from the indexes.